# google caja - run from command line

Tags: google-caja

I've followed the installation steps described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/RunningCaja).
Now they say - "To run the Cajoler from a command-line, use the bin/cajole_html script.", but there is no file `cajole_html` there. (I have checked out the latest source code from their svn repo, and the build went successfully)
And basically the same thing is described [here](http://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/chapter-8.-social-application-security-concepts), look for `Setting Up Caja`.

1. I'm looking for a way to run it from the command line like this:
   `bin/cajole_html -i <htmlInputFile> -o <outputTarget>`
2. What I actually need is to know if the javascript is "dangerous" or not. I don't really need to cajole html/css, only js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is somewhat out of date; Caja is now a purely client-side
library.  See

> https://developers.google.com/caja/

and specifically

> https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/gettingstarted/

for getting started.

Comment: hmm, this is not good news. I'd like to run some js through it, and then save it locally and give it to users. so that the app will be created on my website but it will be run somewhere else. Will caja be of help here ?

Comment: The code no longer needs to be transformed.  Modern browsers implemented Caja's security model natively.  You do need to load the runtime library including the DOM emulation layer, which is what that page explains how to do.  When you say it will be run somewhere else, do you have any control over that environment?  Even under the old Caja, your  code would need the runtime library in order to run.

Comment: So this means that you can not say if some javascript is "safe" or not by evaluating the javascript as a string, or by running it ? Isn't there a way to see what exactly is the js trying to access ? and if it does that then it'll count as safe and if not, then it's not.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing that question.  There is no useful distinction between "safe" javascript and "unsafe".  What Caja does, and has always done, is provide a virtual webpage for the guest code to run in.  The guest code can call any of the APIs exposed by the virtual browser, but the host webpage controls what the APIs actually do.

Comment: For example, the host webpage may prohibit the virtual browser from redirecting; then if the guest code tries to redirect the page, it will simply fail.  The host may restrict the virtual browser to loading images from a specific website; if the code tries to load an image from a different website, it will fail.

Comment: Alan Turing proved in 1936 that there is no algorithm for determining what a piece of code might access.

Comment: thanks for clearing it up. (now I feel like an idiot) :)

Comment: but what if I want that javascript only to be able to modify the DOM and nothing more. From what you said in your last three comments, it is not possible to say if code is safe or not by evaluating/looking at the code. What if a user is giving me a js file, I'm saving the "current state" of the test machine. (by this I mean, everything that javascript has access to) I run the code, I'm looking at the changes, and if I like the changes I say it's good and if I don't like it I return false :)
Does this sound like something achievable ?

Comment: If the code interacts with the user at all, or depends on the date, or calls Math.random, or loads an image, then the changes it makes will be different each time it runs.  Unless you restrict the JavaScript to be completely deterministic, that approach will not work.

Comment: Yes, it should be `completely deterministic`, but I'm not much of an expert in this. Can you give me some hints on where to start ? maybe a book that's worth reading, or something else, general ideas everything is higly appreciated. vrihlea(a)gmail.com

Comment: You can't allow arbitrary access to the DOM and preserve determinism, since the DOM exposes user-generated events.  If you just want to understand determinism, it means that given the same inputs, you always get the same outputs: the inputs *determine* the outputs.  Functional programming advocates often tout determinism as one of the major benefits, since deterministic code is much easier to test.